SPSS: GENLINMIXED command
I want to run a repeated measures fixed-effects binary logistic regression in SPSS.
I know that I have to use the GENLINMIXED command when I want to estimate a model with random effects. But if I do not specify any random effects in the GENLINMIXED model, do I run a repeated measures fixed-effects regression then?
I know that there is also the command GENLIN where we only have fixed effects, but with this command I do not see any option to specify repeated measures or is there a way to do it?

Can't help you with built in sub\commands, but this might be solvable with a restructure of the data into long format (repeated measures are in extra rows instead of columns). If you need help with restructuring start a new question with a description of the present data structure and the end result you need.

Thank you for your suggestion, but I already restructured my data into long format.  The GENLINMIXED model specifically asks for specifying repeated measures, whereas the GENLIN model does not so I am not sure if including the repeated measures in the GENLIN model will correctly take into account the data in long format.

For this question you should try https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
